# Loading daemon at startup

Tags: boot, nginx, lighttpd, services

Is there an elegant way, other than messing with `/etc/rc?.d`, to control the daemon loading at boot time?

My personal concern is stopping [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) from loading at boot, while setting [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) to do load at boot.

Thanks in advance,
Adam

Comment: @karthick87: Startup applications is for gnome session apps, not for system daemons

Comment: Oke what abt **update-rc.d**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to manage service daemons is managing links on /etc/rc?.d, there are some tools which allow you to easily manage the startup order without having to manually change the links.
Install the package "sysv-rc-conf" and run "sysv-rc-conf" from the terminal.

Please note that it doesn't allow you to manage services which use the new Ubuntu init system (upstart), there is no easy way to manage those yet.

Comment: what versions are using upstart?

Comment: Services using upstart have a .conf file at /etc/init/ , to disable services on upstart the easier way is to rename their .conf file to .conf.disable .